# Using SendInput with MinGW in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to use `SendInput()` on Windows but I'm building under MinGW using Eclipse CDT... the header files included with mingw don't expose this function, so I'm wondering if/how you can access such a feature? Or.... is it a trap that can't be avoided thanks to microsoft making all their SDK's only work with visual studio? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue with a little more research. Normally I would delete my posts when I find the solution shortly after but since I couldn't find the solution or anything related to this problem here, I'll post an answer:

"You need `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x500 // or any other value higher than 403` before including windows.h"

From:
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/48595/